# what are the advantages and disadvantages of using ipsec protocol, how vulnerable is it?

Tags: vpn, ipsec

There are several ways through which the VPN can be applied, like SSL, TLS etc. But most of the VPN use IPSec.

What kind vulnerabilities does ipsec possess?